# Some definition in finite group theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading an article about number of sylow subgroups. I have this theorem and don't understand some definitions which I am in italics below .

$\textbf{Theorem.}$ Suppose that $A$ is a finite group ***acting coprimely*** on a fnite group
$G$, and let $H$ be an $A$-*invariant subgroup* of $G$. Let $C = \mathbb{C}_G(A)$. Then $\left[C:C\cap H\right]$
divides $\left[G:H\right]$.

Can you show me these definitions?
 I don't find this definition in any book. Maybe, I'm not knowledgeable enough to find it. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the article please?

Comment: Here you are. https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-10/S0002-9939-03-06884-9/S0002-9939-03-06884-9.pdf

Comment: I have found the definition of $A$-invariant subgroup in Martin Isaacs book [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=pCLhYaMUg8IC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false). See section 3E starting on page $96$, until page $106$. There also coprime is explained (which is boldface above and not italic).

Comment: I would guess that it means that $|A|$ and $|G|$ are coprime.